# How to set option WHERE in offset method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a string in code:

```
@card = Card.offset(rand(Card.count)).where("review_date"<=Time.now).first
```

I need 1 random record with date equal or less current date. but it show the error `invalid date`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@card = Card.where("review_date <= ?" , Time.now).limit(1).offset(rand(Card.count))
```

but here there is an extra overhead of count query first which will run as 
`Card.count` which you are using for offset.

Comment: `PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone <= LINE 1: SELECT "cards".* FROM "cards" WHERE (review_date <=) ORDER... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. : SELECT "cards".* FROM "cards" WHERE (review_date <=) ORDER BY "cards"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 21`

Comment: sorry forget about question mark. my mistake. apologies.